# Remover a parte hora de uma data em c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

isso aqui não está dando certo:

```
DateTime? _data = calDataExclusao.Date;
string nova_data = _data.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

O erro é:

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Como eu removo a parte hora de uma data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, o formato da data está errado. Ele deve ser `dd/MM/yyyy` e não `dd/mm/yyyy`, dessa forma você está pegando os minutos ao invés do mês.

Fonte<sup>(en)</sup>: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

O problema é que você está usando um `Nullable DateTime` e não um `DateTime` normal. Você deve fazer dessa forma

```
string nova_data = _data.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Isso para converter o `DateTime` para `string`, se você quiser realmente **remover a parte hora de uma data** você deve fazer

```
DateTime novaData = _data.Value.Date;
```

Isso fará com que a variável `novaData` fique com a mesma data da anterior, mas com horas, minutos e segundos zerados.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
 _data.Value.ToShortDateString();
```