# Converter "data e horário" para "data" em C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Preciso converter "data e horário" para "data" em C#, mantendo o formato DateTime (sem converter para string).

No código, estou convertendo um objeto para datetime, mas preciso remover o horário dele também para apresentar em um `DataGridTextColumn`.

```
t.DataDeContrato = Convert.ToDateTime(row.ItemArray[6]);
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Remover a parte hora de uma data em c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102638/remover-a-parte-hora-de-uma-data-em-c)

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, pelo jeito, não leu a questão nem os comentários.

Comment: relaxa, se eu confundi, os moderadores irão ignorar a minha sinalização

Comment: Mesmo dizendo que eu não li direito, aceitou a resposta com a mesma solução da questão que citei como duplicata...

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, o Tobias Mesquita comentou a resposta correta nos comentários. É só você ler... o problema era no XAML. Realmente, não leu direito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o `DateTime` possui uma propriedade chamada `Date`.

```
t.DataDeContrato = Convert.ToDateTime(row.ItemArray[6]).Date;
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Na verdade, tenho que alterar a data no componente que exibe a data...

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DataDeContrato}" Header="Data de contrato" />

Comment: Como faço a formatação dentro do DataGridTextColumn?

Comment: neste caso o seu problema é outro, não tem haver com C#, mas com WPF. tente o seguinte: `Binding="{Binding Path=DataDeContrato, StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}"`

Comment: Coloque o comentário como resposta se isso resolveu o problema.